# What is the minimum number of nodes in a cluster?

Tags: marklogic

The documentation says a cluster [needs at least three nodes](https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/cluster/clustering#id_87995). We were able to run on two hosts, and testing failover appeared to work.

We set up two hosts (A, B) in a cluster, each with one forest. The forest on A was the master forest. The forest on B was the replica forest. We attached forest A to a database. At this point the status of forest "A" was "open" and "B" was "sync replicating".

Then we shut down host A. The status of forest B became "open".

It seem like failover worked even though we only had two hosts in the cluster. Is this the expected behavior?

Answer (score 3):

To understand the issue better, try this.
Have host B replicate ALL databases including the Security DB.
(put a forest on B that is a replica of the matching forest on A).
Your description matches whats called "Local Disk Failover"

https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/cluster/failover#id_65543

( the term is misleading, the disks dont need to be "local" they can be on a SAN or physically remote - the term means that each host ONLY sees its own disk, its not a shared disk).

Test you can login and preform operations on A or B reliably 
and the results are seen by both.

Ideally simulate a real world use case by either making a simple app,
like one that updates a document every time you click a button.
Or use the REST services and test you can do the same thing on both hosts.

Now disconnect the network between A and B.
( pull the wire out or disable the network change the router setting, whatever is easiest.)

Now try your application on both hosts.
Go to each host individually to the Admin console and see what it thinks is the status of itself and the other host.  What do you expect the status to show ?
Both A and B no longer can communicate so they each believe the other host has failed.
Without a 3rd host to arbitrate ... what would you expect or want the result to be ?
Should both hosts stop working ?  or should both hosts keep working ?
Or should only one work ? which one ? How would they decide ?
Should the "Failover" host take over as master because it sees the master as failed ?
Or should the master decide the failover host has failed ?
BOTH choices are correct - in the context that nothing else is known, 
you want the cluster to keep going.

Now try this
Use the app to add or modify documents on both systems.  Would it work ?
Make different changes to the same document on each host.
Do you expect that each app keep functioning ?  It should, thats what failover is for.
But each thinks the other is dead so they dont attempt to replicate, instead they
both act as masters (or they both fail -  they cant tell the difference
so there is no way to pick which is better)

Now reconnect the network after A and B both have different changes.
What do you expect will occur ? 
What changes from A and B will be replicated ?
Will B give up being the master and hand over its changes to A ?
or will A realize B has just now recovered and send ITS changes over to B?
what about the documents both changed ?

Another (more complex but illuminating) experiment is to set a load balancer between you and the cluster.  That will send requests to both hosts over time.

Now disconnect the network between the hosts but not between the load balencer and each host.
Run your app ... it will still belive its just talking to "one host" as before.
But changes will be sent to A and B depending on the load balencer.
What do you expect the user experience to be ?
If Request 1 updates A then request 2 fetches the document from B ...
The user (and app) would get inconsistent results - if any at all.
This is not good.

Failover happened ... but the system as a whole is inconsistent and not aware of it.
It would work in the experiment you tried because you *know* to only talk to A. 
But thats not the purpose of failover.  You can accomplish that with RAID or distributed filesystems or simple continous backups ...

Failover is about being able to handle either system going offline *or disconnected from each other*
and the cluster as a whole still function and stay consistent regardless of what host you send requests to.

With 3 hosts it can do that from all 3 hosts working to all 3 completely offline or disconnected,
it will not operate in a inconsistant way.  Requests to any host will either succeed and be consistent with the rest, or it will fail (because the host is offline or it has determined it is not part of the cluster anymore).

With 2 hosts (or any even number) you cannot achieve "failover" with both consistency and replication reliably.

You can do "replication" (see Database Replication and Flexible Replication) between clusters,
even clusters of 1 node .. but that is not the same as "failover"
Replication is one way .. a Master sends data to the Replica.
If either fails you can decide to send traffic to the other ... but at that point
you need manual intervention later to try to bring the data back into sync.

You can see the differences in 
https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/database-replication

Answer (score 0):

For failover to work, a cluster needs at least three hosts. With only two hosts there is the danger of a "[split brain](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Split-brain_%28computing%29)" problem, for example if a network link fails.